# Проверка словаря на нескольких значений и вывод их в отдельную переменую

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть словарь

```
taxonomy = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 
            'key3': 'value3', 'key4': 'value4',
            'key5': 'value5', 'key6': 'value6'}
```

и список `cat = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key7', 'key8']` из которого я перебором `category = list(map(taxonomy.get, cat))` нахожу совпадения. Сами значения списка поделены на группы (Например: `'key1','key3'` это группа `Service1`, а `'key2','key7','key8'` это группа `Service2`).Как сделать так что совпадения  category еще разделить на группы?

Comment: Результатом `category = list(map(taxonomy.get, cat))` будет `[None, None, None, None, None]`, так как ни один из элементов `cat` не является ключом `taxonomy`

Comment: Поправил вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не очень понятно, что конкретно вы хотите сделать, но для группировки значений можно использовать функцию `groupby` из стандартного модуля `itertools`:

```py
from itertools import groupby

taxonomy = {
    'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2',
    'key3': 'value3', 'key4': 'value4',
    'key5': 'value5', 'key6': 'value6',
}

groups = {
    'value1': 'Service1', 'value2': 'Service1', 'value3': 'Service1',
    'value4': 'Service2', 'value5': 'Service2', 'value6': 'Service2',
}

# кажется в вашем вопросе `cat` должен содержать ключи
# я поправил и переименовал
keys = ['key2', 'key3', 'key4', 'key7', 'key8']
values = list(map(taxonomy.get, keys))
print(f'Values: {values}')

for group, group_keys in groupby(values, key=groups.get):
    print(f'Group: {group}, keys: {list(group_keys)}')
```

Вывод:

> Values: ['value2', 'value3', 'value4', None, None]
> Group: Service1, keys: ['value2', 'value3']
> Group: Service2, keys: ['value4']
> Group: None, keys: [None, None]

Comment: А как обратиться к каждой группе отдельно или поставить переменные каждой группе?

Comment: @SANCHOS Вариантов предостаточно, всё зависит от вашей конкретной задачи и цели. Например, можно сложить полученные значения в словарь.

Comment: Мне нужно создать переменную с названием группы, а в середине переменной будет список этой группы

Comment: Нашел решение которое подходит мне  ```dic[group] = list(group_keys)```